# a weird issue of syntax highlighting file in vim

Tags: vim

I've a syntax highlighting file including two entities, test and config:

```
syn region myTestConfigEntity start="\<test\>" end="\<endtest\>" contains=myTestConfigProperty
syn region myTestConfigEntity start="\<config\>" end="\<endconfig\>" contains=myTestConfigProperty
hi def link myTestConfigEntity Todo
syn match myTestConfigProperty “<source\>" contained
hi def link myTestConfigProperty Identifier
```

it's weird that this worked for config entity, not for test entity. here is an experiment:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code.

First, the curly quote in:

```
syn match myTestConfigProperty “<source\>" contained
                               ^
```

Second, the missing backslash in the same line:

```
syn match myTestConfigProperty “<source\>" contained
                                ^
```

Fixed:

```
syn match myTestConfigProperty "\<source\>" contained
```

Now, with the fix in place your code is working as expected:

[image: screenie]

Comment: thanks romainl, the second issue is my typo